# Finding the nearest distance between points in a grid cell

Tags: raster, r, point, point-in-polygon

I'm trying to find the distance between the nearest points in a grid-cell, such that there is no equivalence relation between these points. Meaning if there are three points {a, b, c}, then a = b; not b = a; though b = c; and c = a.

This of course only works if there are an odd number of points in a cell, otherwise, if there's an even number, or a single point in a cell, then pick any point in the nearest cell. Furthermore, these points cannot overlap between regions, where the dataset has points on a map with boundaries.

The output should return a data from likeso:

```
Points  cells   region  distance
 pt1     1      canada    2000
 pt2     1      canada    1800
 pt3     2      canada    2100
  .      .        .         .
```

Code that has points (habitat) on a map in North America:

```
uk.map <- getData('GADM', country='USA', level=1)

file1 <- "modis_mcd12q1_umd_2010.tif"

dir.create("data", showWarnings = FALSE)
if (!file.exists(file.path("data", file1))) {
  download.file(paste0("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lime-n/test/main/raster/", file1),
                file.path("data", file1), mode = "wb")
}

r <- raster("data/modis_mcd12q1_umd_2010.tif")

us.map <- st_as_sf(us.map)

rr <- us.map %>% 
  st_transform(crs = projection(r)) %>% 
  rasterize(r) %>% 
  # remove any empty cells at edges
  trim()
```

[image: Diagram]

Comment: I'm struggling with the first paragraph. What do you mean by "equivalence relation" with respect to points? What is the equality sign in "a=b" etc mean?

Comment: @Spacedman I mean it in the sense surjectivity, relative to mathematics, where you can have more than one point in distance to another, however, it cannot be equivalent to the point that matches it. I'll add a diagram for clarification.

Comment: Fixed the diagram. Is this dependent on the order you choose to find the nearest valid point? Why in diagram 2 has B not got C or C not got B as a nearest?

Comment: I probably should have spaced C and B effectively to convey the right interpretation. But, assuming that C and B are spaced at even distance away from A, such that the distance between C and B is greater than their distance to A, then choose the distance to A. Regarding order, I presume that every point could be matched this way, given that any single point in a cell will always have a point either beside it or in another cell to match, given that the other point does not equate to the other point.

Comment: Although, could something like this be visually mapped? Like points on a map, with lines that represent the diagram above. I presume this could look messy if there are far too many points.